# How can I change the iTunes U folder on Mac?

Tags: itunes, itunes-u

I want save all files from **iTunes U** in a device. How can I change the destination folder only for **iTunes U** and continue using the actual folder for all other files?

Answer (score 1):

I made a symbolic link.

```
    ln -s /path/to/iTunes U/content /path/to/where/iTunes/is/looking
```